# PeriodicSequence does not drain

Tags: apache-beam, dataflow, apache-beam-io

I've implemented the following code (which works as expected) to generate a side input every X seconds for an incoming pubsub stream main input. Thing is that the Drain operation in Dataflow does not end / do not work

```
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    side_input = (
            p | beam.Create([None]) | beam.Map(lambda _: (first_timestamp, last_timestamp, interval))
            | PeriodicSequence() | beam.ParDo(TableSchema(), known_args.table)
            | beam.WindowInto(window.GlobalWindows(), trigger=Repeatedly(AfterProcessingTime()),
                              accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
    )

    # main stream
    p | 'ReadPubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.subscription) \
        | 'ShapeEvent' >> beam.ParDo(ShapeEvent(), pvalue.AsDict(side_input)) \
        | 'WriteBQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                                        known_args.table,
                                        schema=None,
                                        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
                                        additional_bq_parameters={'timePartitioning': {
                                            'type': known_args.partition_type
                                        }}
                                    )
```

Comment: Why is your windowing logic applied to the side_input rather than the main input?

Comment: To enable the triggering after each time the table schema is fetched (processed). I assume the main input is in Global window by default.. BTW-i was updated from dataflow team "GCP currently do not support draining the pipelines with Splittable DoFns". Thus, right now i'm working on generating my own Pulse DoFN that will be Drainable.. will update once I get it running

Comment: @ronenp Have you figure out a way to run the side input and be able to drain the job?